# Pairwise unique combinations ignoring the direction

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to aggregate a certain value in a data.frame based on a common character in R. 
The Problem is that I am not interested in different directions of the pairwise combination.
So for instance

```
d = data.frame( x = LETTERS[1:5], y = LETTERS[5:1] )

  x y
1 A E
2 B D
3 C C
4 D B
5 E A
```

The combination would be then calculated like this:

```
d$z <- paste0(d$x,d$y,sep="_")
```

The problem is that i am not interested in pairwise differences. So `A_E` should be the same as `E_A` in this simple example.

Is there a clever short solution to paste them? I am currently thinking about sorting each one before combining them into a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `pmin` and `pmax`:

```
transform(d, z = paste(pmin(x,y), pmax(x,y), sep="_"))
#  x y   z
#1 A E A_E
#2 B D B_D
#3 C C C_C
#4 D B B_D
#5 E A A_E
```

Note that you might need to convert x and y to `character` if they are `factor`s.

---

```
d <- data.frame( x = LETTERS[1:5], y = LETTERS[5:1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative, which has the only advantage that it works for factors, characters, or basically any other class.

```
d$z <- apply(d, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="_"))
#> d
#  x y   z
#1 A E A_E
#2 B D B_D
#3 C C C_C
#4 D B B_D
#5 E A A_E
```